# Can two processes run the same method at the exact same time on a single-core CPU machine?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have studied that an operating system time-slices the processes.

I know that we should design a multi-thread application assuming that it may be run on multicore CPU. Just for the sake of knowledge, I want to know if there is a possibility of two processes running the same method at the exact same time on a **single-core CPU** machine.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the fact it's the same method doesn't make any difference. On a single core machine, there is presumably only one CPU thread, which means only a single line of execution. The OS will typically preempt long running processes and switch between them to simulate multitasking. That doesn't mean that they're running at the same though. So strictly speaking, the answer is No.

Comment: It depends if you count (Intel) hyperthreads as cores.

Comment: Watch out: You mention a multi-threaded application and ask about two processes. The isolation between processes is usually big enough so you can run the same code in two processes. Simultaneously as much as your cores allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...run the same method at the exact same time...

The answer depends on what you think that phrase means.

In order to understand the execution of a program, you have to talk about *events,* and the order in which events happen. Events are instantaneous, and on a single core machine no two *events* can ever happen at the same time.

But, "running a method" is not an event. Running a method is the *interval* between two events; The first event is the method call, and the second event is the return.  Even on a single-core machine, two method calls can be *overlapped:*

```
  method call A      method call B
  ----------------   ----------------
  - entered
    does some work
                     - entered            v
                       does some work     | during this span of time
    does some work                        | the two method calls are
                       does some work     | _overlapped._
                 ...                      |
                     - returns            ^
    does some work
  - returns
```

---

> ...the same method...

Watch out there! "Thread-safety" is practically never a question of which *methods* are called by the application's threads. It's a question of which *data* the methods operate on.

Two overlapping calls to the same method can operate on different data, and have no impact on thread-safety whatsoever.

Two overlapping calls to different methods can operate on the same data, and need to use mutexes or other special means to ensure that they do not interfere with each other and corrupt the data as a result.

Comment: "Events are instantaneous, and on a single core machine no two events can ever happen at the same time." With super scalar CPUs and HT cores, the above becomes contentious.

Comment: @pveentjer, Sure. We can describe the behavior of a computer solely in terms of user interactions, describe it solely in terms of the interactions of individual electrons and atoms, and we can describe it, probably, on hundreds of other levels. in-between. In order for our programs to make sense, there has to be some intermediate level of description—call it the "machine model"—that satisfies the needs of app developers and compiler writers. Beneath that level, the hardware guys can do whatever to improve performance, so long as the machine behaves _as if_ the machine model was true.

Comment: The machine model needs to be simple enough for an individual to hold it all in their head. One simplification, for a single-processor machine, is to say that no two events ever happen "at the same time." Even when we describe multi-processor machines, we don't let it get much more complicated than that. (E.g., A typical, multi-cpu machine model will not allow any two threads in a correctly synchronized program to update or access the same shared primitive variable "at the same time.")

Answer (score 0):

The answer is straightforward **we cannot do multithreading in a single-core CPU**
as we need at least two cores to run a thread simultaneously.

Comment: You can do multi-threading on a single-core CPU, but only one thread will be scheduled on the CPU at a single point in time.

Comment: And with hyper threading, you still have 2 threads running at the same moment on the same CPU.